# Dojo parameterless constructor calls base constructor with parameters

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor, dojo

Is it possible in javascript / dojo toolkit to call the base constructor with explicitely
set constructor arguments (out of the constructor of the inherited class)

```
dojo.provide("ClassA");
dojo.declare("ClassA", null,
{
  constructor: function(text)
  {
    console.log(text);
  }
});

dojo.provide("ClassB");
dojo.declare("ClassB", ClassA,
{
   constructor: function()
   {
      // want to call the base constructor of Class A with "Hello "
      console.log("world!");
   }
});
```

I could use this.inherited(arguments, ["Hello "]) but this will produce two calls of the base constructor (one without and one with the given argument).
(will produce output of: undefined\n"Hello "\n"world!").

I already tried using the following ways:

```
dojo.mixin(this, "Hello");
dojo.safeMixin(this, "Hello");
dojo.mixin(ClassA, "Hello");
...
```

but all things I did seems to call the base constructor twice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off automatic constructor chaing. Take a look [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html#default-constructor-chaining) for an example of how to manually override automatic behaviour.